Cancellation property of vector bundles
Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring of dim d and $ Y=Spec R[X_1,\ldots, X_n]= SpecR \times_{SpecZ} Spec Z[X_1,\ldots, X_n]$. Consider $U$ to be locally free sheaf of finite type over Y with rank $\geq max\{d+1,2\}$. For any locally free sheaf $V$ and $W$  of finite type over Y, such that $U \oplus V \cong W \oplus V$. We know by Bass and Suslin's result on cancellation, that $U \cong W$. I am interested to know  what happens in the following case: In Y, if Spec R is replaced with an arbitrary Noetherian scheme $X$ of dimension $d$ such that $T= X \times_{Spec Z} Spec(Z[X_1,\ldots, X_n])$. If $U$ is a locally free sheaf of finite type over T with rank $\geq max\{d+1,2\}$, V and W are locally free sheaf of finite type over T such that $U \oplus V \cong W \oplus V$. What can we say about isomorphism  $U \cong W$ that is about cancellation of $U$.(Here Z denotes set of all integers)

I am trying to understand about the geometric analogue of cancellation of projective modules from above question.
